# How to create a Subject in rxJS that changes the value after timeout?

Tags: angular, rxjs, timeout

I have a snackbar subject implemented like this, where a message shall appear for 4 seconds in an Angular app:

```js
    snackbar = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);
    showMessage(message: string) {
        this.snackbar.next(message);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.snackbar.next(null);
        },4000)
    }
```

I was wondering if it is possible to implement this in a more rxjs-like fashion, like a pipe right after the definition, with a timeout there and a new value after 4 seconds. Is this possible or is my solution how you would do that?

Comment: Seems fine to me, but you should be careful with `setTimeout`. In your case, any message you send up to 4 seconds after the last message might get hidden too quickly since the previous timeout will empty the subject.

Comment: you're right, I actually need some kind of queue. I thought rxJS might have an operator that helps here.

Comment: Are you using snackbars from any standard library like Angular Material or are you implementing your own?

Comment: I use my own -  very basic one for a pseudo shop system that will be used for E2E tests, so it's not too important if this doesn't work perfectly. I was just curious how you could deal with this in rxJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rxjs way of implementation. Everytime when you emit a message it pair with the `null` value emission. `concatMap` will ensure you never miss any message pushed to the queue

```
import { of, map, Observable, Subject, timer, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, mapTo, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
const message = new Subject();
setInterval(() => message.next(Math.random()), 6000);
message
  .pipe(concatMap((value) => merge(of(value), timer(4000).pipe(mapTo(null)))))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

you can use this observable as the source for snackbar message, `message` subject will serve as message emitter.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cupp2f?file=index.ts